# i want to filter my datagrid view

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to filter my DataGridView based on two textboxes (first name(`fname`) and second name(`sname`), but it gets filtered just based on `fname`

Here is my code:

```
Try

Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "\Kyc.mdb"

    Dim cmdfilter As String = " select ID as الرقم_الوطني,fname as الاسم_الاول,sname as الاسم_الثاني,thname as الاسم_الثالث,finame as الاسم_الرابع from O_name where fname like '%" & fname.Text & "' OR sname like '%" & sname.Text & " ' "
    Dim cmdcommand As New OleDbCommand
    Dim dataadabtar As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim table As New DataTable

    With cmdcommand
        .CommandText = cmdfilter
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    With dataadabtar
        .SelectCommand = cmdcommand
        .Fill(table)
    End With


    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
        With DataGridView1
            .Rows.Add(table.Rows(i)("الرقم_الوطني"), table.Rows(i)("الاسم_الاول"), table.Rows(i)("الاسم_الثاني"), table.Rows(i)("الاسم_الثالث"), table.Rows(i)("الاسم_الرابع"))
        End With
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)

End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cmdfilter As String = " select ID as الرقم_الوطني,fname as الاسم_الاول,sname as الاسم_الثاني,thname as الاسم_الثالث,finame as الاسم_الرابع from O_name where fname like '%" & fname.Text & "' OR sname like '%" & sname.Text & " ' Order by fname,Sname"
```

first Preference give fname and second preference give sname

Comment: nothing happens when i try this code  i have tow rows have same fname but different sname .. when i try this both rows appears in result but i want just one when i type sname